# why django project failed deploying? - django + nginx + uwsgi

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, python, django, uwsgi

I am trying to deploy a Django project through Nginx and uWSGI. If I run the project manually running `python manage.py runserver :8000` it works fine, so the project itself is not the problem I guess.

I installed Django and dependencies inside a dedicated virtualenv, and put the project in. I also installed nginx and uwsgi OUTSIDE the virtualenv, and started creating config files:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` (symlinked in sites-enabled):

```
upstream uwsgi_myproject {
    server 127.0.0.1:5678;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.url.net;
    set $home /path/to/myvirtualenv;
    access_log /path/to/myvirtualenv/log/access_uwsgi.log;
    error_log /path/to/myvirtualenv/log/error_uwsgi.log;

    client_max_body_size 10m;
    keepalive_timeout 120;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi_myproject;
        include uwsgi_params;
        gzip on;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR $home/path/to/myproject;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT uwsgi;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME $home;
        root $home;
    }
    location /static/  {
        alias /path/to/myvirtualenv/path/to/myproject/static/;
        expires max;
        autoindex off;
    }
    location /media_adm/  {
        alias /path/to/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/static/;
        autoindex off;
    }
}
```

`/etc/init/uwsgi_myproject.conf`:

```
description "uWSGI starter for myproject"

start on (local-filesystems and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

exec /path/to/myvirtualenv/bin/uwsgi \
--uid venvowner \
--home /path/to/myvirtualenv \
--pythonpath /path/to/myvirtualenv/path/to/myproject/ \
--socket 127.0.0.1:5678 \
--chmod-socket \
--module wsgi \
-b 8192 \
--logdate \
--optimize 2 \
--processes 2 \
--master \
--logto /path/to/myvirtualenv/log/uwsgi.log
```

`/path/to/myvirtualenv/path/to/myproject/wsgi.py`:

```
import os, sys, site

site.addsitedir('/path/to/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Then I rebooted the machine and try to connect to my.url.net, but there's no response(when I installed nginx before importing myproject, it responded with "Welcome to Nginx!"). I noticed with `lsof | grep LISTEN` that the upstream socket hasn't been created. **The logs don't output anything relevant**, so I tried to execute uwsgi manually with the same parameters than `uwsgi_myproject.conf` and obtained this output:

```
current working directory: /etc/init
detected binary path: /path/to/myvirtualenv/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 6674
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.
```

**EDIT: So the last thing I tried was reordering the parameters. Now the --socket parameter is successfully processed, but I still obtain this message in the output lines:**

```
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

Some documents I've been reading:

- [Running uWSGI via Upstart](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html)
- [Nginx support](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html)
- [Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

**Any ideas about what am I missing or overlooking?**

**CONTINUE:** I reviewed the docs again and try a different approach: using an .ini file and run it manually to see what happens:

It is a bit ugly, but here goes:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:5678
uid = venvowner
chdir = /path/to/myvirtualenv
home = /path/to/myvirtualenv
virtualenv = /path/to/myvirtualenv
pythonpath = /path/to/myvirtualenv/path/to/myproject
module = wsgi
master = true
optimize = 2
processes = 2
logto = /path/to/myvirtualenv/log/uwsgi.log
```

I obtained some useful logs:

```
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
ImportError: No module named wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

**The workers are spawned, but the stack obviously fails. I'll take this on another day.**

Comment: I want to apologize for the lack of updatings. I've been very busy this month so I didn't have time to try to find a solution to this. In addition, I am almost clueless. I have overlooked something for sure, but I have no idea what it is, or what should I try from now on. Maybe I should summarize the question better than this?

Comment: I think uwsgi can't find your wsgi file. Try to add a full path to your wsgi file in the --module option. Also take a look at --chdir option. In addition pythonpath should contain path to virtualenv not the project folder

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, @DhirajThakur. Using an absolute path may be the solution to the problem. I will try it out when I have somemore time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally, I made it work.** Thanks to @DhirajThakur for his comment, which helped me to look into the right direction.

`/etc/init/uwsgi_myproject.conf`:

```
description "uWSGI starter for myproject"

start on (local-filesystems and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi /etc/init/myproject.ini
```

`/etc/init/myproject.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
socket = 127.0.0.1:5678
uid = venvowner
chdir = /path/to/myvirtualenv
home = /path/to/myvirtualenv
virtualenv = /path/to/myvirtualenv
pythonpath = /path/to/myvirtualenv/path/to/myproject
wsgi-file = /path/to/myvirtualenv/path/to/myproject/wsgi.py
optimize = 2
processes = 2
logto = /path/to/myvirtualenv/log/uwsgi.log
```

Somehow, I've got the feeling that the way I did resolve the problem is a little ugly tough.